# Debug LaTeX in Visual Studio Code (with LaTeX-Workshop)

Tags: debugging, ide, vscode, latex-workshop

Visual Studio Code seems to be very useful with [LaTeX-Workshop plugin](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop). In comparison to TeXStudio, TeXMaker, etc. it is able to autoformat code. It is very useful when I search for an unmatched environment. I wrote my about it notes [How to use Visual Studio Code for LaTeX](https://jankoweb.tumblr.com/post/675626624630358016/view-james-yulatex-workshop-wiki).

**Debug problem**

But, I have a problem with debug. Sometimes I have an unmatched bracket and I can't see it from formatted code. So I want to debug it. I am able to set Breakpoint but it does not work.

I searched for plugins that are able to debug or search for unmatched brackets, but I found nothing. Comment parts of code are very boring when I have a big project with includes. It takes a lot of time. Last error was in my beamer project that consist of 11 tex files (`\input{}`) and the problem was one of included file in:

```
\begin{alertblock}{\textsc{test}
        \begin{itemize}
```

It takes a general error in index file:

```
File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body.
Emergency stop.
```

Finally, I found the missing bracket after "\textsc{test}" by commenting parts of code, but it takes 20 minutes;(

**Question:** *Do you know how to debug LaTeX code in Visual Studio Code effectively or how to find unmatched brackets?*

Comment: I also use VS Code, always compile after some edit so you are sure the recent part you are writing has no problem.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry It does not work for me:( Maybe I write changes too quickly:-D

Comment: Well, I recompile several times even when just one complex equation.  (Maybe I am just too cautious.)